# Erase partitions to expand another one

Tags: partitioning, windows-10

My Disk 0 has 4 partitions:

1. one where Windows 10 is installed [126Go]
2. two smaller for Ubuntu (highlighted in red) [24.65Go]+[15.98Go]

I would like to erase those two Ubuntu partitions from the Windows interface and use the freed space to augment the size of the Windows partition [126Go+24.65Go+15.98Go] without reinstalling everything.

A strategy that I have in mind is to create an image of the Windows partition, erase the two Ubuntu partition and format the new bigger partition. Copy the image onto the new partition.

Will this work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making that too complicated. Just delete those 2 partitions until you have **unallocated** space and add that to the C partition. That is a 5 minute operation.

Comment: ok thanks. But I've read somewhere that it could affect the C: partition in a bad way. I am not sure to understand your "unallocated space"?

Comment: I don't see how it could effect the C partition negatively. And unallocated space as opposed to freespace. Because with freespace you still have a partition holding it of which you have to get rid.